# Error AADSTS90093 on Microsoft "converged" OAuth authorize for organizational O365 account

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an application that I registered with Microsoft at apps.dev.microsoft.com to use their new "converged" OAuth2 flow documented at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/.

I am requesting authorization for scope `user.read`. Specifically, this is the authorize URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=77ebf38a-23aa-4006-b947-aae863964ba7&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44302%2Fazure_connection%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user.read
```

I expect this to work 100% of the time as I'm only asking for the `user.read` scope, which is documented at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes as not requiring delegation. However, for my corporate (aka organizational) account, when I login to the authorize URL I get the error `AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent.` My corp organizational account is a regular user role in our AAD.

Every other authorize request works as expected. I've tested this with other organizational accounts who are admins, contributors, and regular users in other Azure accounts I have. I've tested this with "MSA" accounts (outlook.com, hotmail.com, other Live-registered accounts) too.

The only differences in accounts that I can think of:

- The account that fails is an Office 365 account. (Every other test I've done with an organizational account has been me manually entering the account in AAD in "the old portal".)
- The account that fails is the account under which I registered the app on apps.dev.microsoft.com (Oh the irony!)

Anyone encountering this? Do you see anything wrong with the authorize URL or the authorization scope? Is there some setting in AAD or in Office 365 that could prevent third-party OAuth access to "myself"?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the global administrator in your organization has blocked users from giving consent to applications.

You need to work with your global administrator(s) to have them allow users to provide consent to applications. This setting can be found in the classic Azure Management portal, in Active Directory -> Configure -> Integrated Applications: "USERS MAY GIVE APPLICATIONS PERMISSION TO ACCESS THEIR DATA"

Comment: Not sure that #1 works on the v2 endpoint.  #2 is correct, AND may also be changed using Azure AD PowerShell - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194127 and the UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled option.

Comment: Good catch. I've removed #1 from the response since as per my testing, prompt=admin_consent is not yet available in the v2 endpoint.